# DOM fails to render property change in Vuejs

Tags: api, vuejs2

I am getting data with axios from an API , i manage to iterate with v-for through each property and i want @click to show the child properties ONLY of the CLICKED element.

//api gives

```
  Subject_title: (...)
  showChildren: false <-- This is added during the call with forEach
  subject_id: (...)
  subjects: (...)
```

And the rest is:

```
 const vm = new Vue({
     el: "#app",
     data() {
        return {
         results: [],
     }
},
     methods: {
        toggleChildren(i) {
        this.results[i].showChildren =!this.results[i].showChildren;
        }
      },

     mounted() {
      axios.get(url).then(response => {
       this.results = response.data.result;
       this.results.forEach(sub => {
           sub["showChildren"] = false
           });
      });
}
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="subjects-single" v-for="(result,i) in results" :key="i">

  <div  @click="toggleChildren(i)" class="subjects-title">

     <span class="accordion-title__text">

     {{ result.Subject_title }} {{i}}

    </span>

    <ul v-if="results[i].showChildren">

     <li v-for="subject in result.subjects">

       {{ subject.Subject_title }} </li>

    </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is not ractive if you directly change an array item with the index, you must use Vue.set.

```
Vue.set(this.results, indexOfItem, newValue)
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Comment: Thanks for your input, i tried :

 Vue.set(this.results[i], this.results[i].showChildren, true )

 but wasn't successful:
      

results {

     0:
       Subject_title: (...)
       showChildren: false   <--
       subject_id: (...)
       subjects: (...)

     1:
       Subject_title: (...)
       showChildren: false  <--
       subject_id: (...)
       subjects: (...)

     2:
       Subject_title: (...)
       showChildren: false <--
       subject_id: (...)
       subjects: (...)
     }

how about:

vm.results[i].showChildren =  !vm.results[i].showChildren

Comment: Take a closer look at the method signature of `Vue.set`, you're using it wrong: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set